# Crystal lang takes option parameters from OptionParser when it shouldn't

Tags: crystal-lang, optionparser

I started paying around with **Crystal** lang, I want to use **OptionParser** to show a help text, however *-h* will be interpred by *Crystal* instead of *OptionParser*

I am using the example from https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.18.7/OptionParser.html

and calling the app *myAppl* with:

```
crystal src/myAppl.cr --help
```

This shows Crystal help.
Now, if I compile the app then it shows the help text I wrote **OptionParser**

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the first line of that help output:

```
Usage: crystal run [options] [programfile] [--] [arguments]
```

That `--` is what allows you to force an argument to be passed to the compiled program rather than being used by the compiler. So following your example:

```
crystal src/myApp1.cr -- --help
```

Of course if you compile your program you can just pass it directly to the resulting binary:

```
crystal build src/myApp1.cr
./myApp1 --help
```